# how to load the css , js from the /resource/js and /resource/css of laravel 6.x?

Tags: php, laravel

inside the blade view file, I added this inside the

```
{{ Html::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }} 
{{ Html::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
```

it cannot load. I also tried these below, but didn't work

```
{{ Html::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }} 
{{ Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
```

despite of having the collectivehtml installed already in my /config/app.php

Comment: rename app.php to app.blade.php  laravel use blade

Comment: why do i need to rename a config file into a blade file? that doesn't make sense

Comment: ohh sorry that is config

Answer (score 0):

Inside your layouts->app.blade.php file, you should be able to load the css like normal like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

as for JavaScript at the end of your body...

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: are you using laravel 6.x ? ....I said I am not able to load the css and js files ...i don't know why are the css and js folders are located under the resource directory by default

Comment: Yes in a previous project. Do you not have any css or js under your public directory?

Comment: laravel 6.x by default the /js , /css are all located inside the /resource directory

Comment: "The Public Directory
The public directory contains the index.php file, which is the entry point for all requests entering your application and configures autoloading. This directory also houses your assets such as images, JavaScript, and CSS."

My public directory has my compiled sass file, which is located in the resource directory but compiles to public. Same goes with JS.

Answer (score 0):

use `aaset()` helper

```php
asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') 
asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset

Comment: css worked, but the js did not...not sure why this doesn't work `<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: synatx is correct check your public dir js/jquery.min.js should be there